# How to configure WCF Service to AutoStart in AppFabric when the services reside in the website root

Tags: iis, wcf, appfabric

I'm trying to configure my WCF services under WIndows Server 2008 R2's IIS and AppFabric to auto-start, but the [steps listed at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677285(v=azure.10).aspx) are possible only when the services reside in an application, but in my case, the .svc files reside directly in the site root.

This way, the 'Configure WCF and WF...' shows as '...for Site' and do not show the options for auto-start, as it would do if the application were hosted under an application sub-folder.

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [answered over here on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dublin/thread/be6bbfd0-5187-4004-ae04-080dd9331d82), the one from SilverNinja is a better answer.

> I found that the IIS UI is not that great for configuring applications
>   - especially when trying to setup the Site Root as an autostart application. The best way to manage it is by using the [Configuration
>   Editor](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevelopertips/archive/2009/01/11/tip-42-did-you-know-configurationeditor-allows-you-to-generate-c-javascript-or-appcmd-script-to-update-configuration.aspx) that comes with AppFabric under the `Computer Name ->
>   Management of Features` View.
>
> To make a Site Root an autostart application - you need to locate the
>   Section `system.applicationHost/sites` and click the (Collection)
>   entry. Click on your site name in the list of sites and click
>   (Collection) once more. Select the application in the list and assign
>   the `serviceAutoStart="True"`, `serviceAutoStartMode="All"`, and
>   `serviceAutoStartProvider="Service"`. Also enter net.pipe for the
>   `enabledProtocols` ("http, net.pipe").
>
> You also need to change the application pool setting to
>   `AlwaysRunning`. To locate this setting, use the Collection Editor to
>   navigate to the Section `system.applicationHost/applicationPools`.
>   Click the (Collection) value and then select the application pool used
>   by your root site and assign `startMode="AlwaysRunning"`.
>
> At this point, you can script your changes via "Generate Script" or
>   apply them immediately using the "Apply" action. Hopefully this helps
>   someone else who was as confused as I was about the issue. To test the
>   configuration, you can issue an `iisreset` to see if your `w3wp.exe`
>   process starts immediately.
>
> [Autostart Configuration MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677285.aspx)

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: HopelessN00b, thanks for fixing my answer. Scott Pack, I'll keep that in mind.